# Having trouble receiving filter subscription mails

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

I don't get any filter subscription emails for almost a week now. Something must have happened with the stackexchange subscription service at about the last weekend.

I can configure subscriptions with a number of different e-mail addresses. Subscriptions
do work with some but do not work with others. Unfortunately, they don't work with the address I've been using for years. Nothing has changed on my side. However, I've double 
checked spam logs and alike to completely exclude mishap on my side.

I've already posted [Have there been modifications recently with filter subscriptions page on stackexchange.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233505/190546) at meta.stackexchange and I have sent a request to the stackexchange team.

However, the situation remains dissatisfactory.

Any clue?

Comment: Seems to be working again. The stackDCmove must be over ;) https://twitter.com/hashtag/stackDCmove?f=realtime&src=hash

Comment: @VonC: DC migration over, receiving filter subscription messages for about 8 hours now.