# Email subscriptions for tags not being delivered

Tags: support, bug, subscriptions

I've seen other questions like this:

- [Subscription Email based on tags suddenly stopped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346229/subscription-email-based-on-tags-suddenly-stopped)
- [Feed email notification misfiring?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345357/feed-email-notification-misfiring)
- [Having trouble receiving filter subscription mails](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258523/having-trouble-receiving-filter-subscription-mails)

But they seem to be somewhat old and I'm not sure if my issue is related. I subscribe to a couple of different tags (`autofac` being one) and for the last, oh, month or so I *thought* no questions were being asked with that tag but it turns out I just wasn't getting the emails. Nothing's in my spam folder, it's just... not there.

Has something changed? Should I try re-creating my subscriptions or something?

Comment: I can confirm this. The emails suddenly stopped being delivered after October 4.

Comment: Ooo! But I do get notified if someone comments on my stuff like @default locale just did. So it's not _all_ notifications, just subscriptions to tags.

Comment: I too have this issue, for a week so I am not getting email notification and I am searching for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had an issue after our network-wide roll out of Entity Framework Core that resulted in lazy loading not always working - in particular it started to fail in certain cases when sending tag subscriptions.

Tag subscriptions can have an email associated directly with the subscription or fallback to using the user's email address. In this case the fallback was using lazy loading and returning null because of the failure.

A fix has been deployed and emails should be sent out over the coming hours

Comment: I see that about 10 questions tagged `autofac` have been asked since October 17 yet I haven't received any emails to my subscription on that tag. Is this fix still being propagated out or is something still broken?

Comment: I'm still not getting anything. I just deleted and re-created my subscription and it says I should be getting a confirmation email to confirm my subscription. How long does that take? I'm going on like 20+ minutes and I've been trying to resend the confirmation but no luck. It says it resent, but nothing is coming through.

Comment: @TravisIllig emails are sent from the stackoverflow.email domain - is it possible something is blocking it?

Comment: I have a forwarder that goes from my primary email to gmail. I had set that up and it wasn't coming through. I put my gmail account directly in and got the confirmation. However, I don't know if the failure is on the StackOverflow end in sending or on my forwarder end in receiving and forwarding. Reason being, I get TONS of other email to my forwarder with zero issues. This particular StackOverflow thing is the only thing having trouble. I guess it can live on my gmail account for now, but it'd be nice to know why it's not working on my other account.

Comment: @TravisIllig any errors from the forwarder? I can't see anything on this end. I can run a test using your forwarding address tomorrow when I get in. Would you mind pinging me an email at dward@ please?

Comment: I tracked it down and the forwarder added some sort of spam filter without telling me. Apparently the SO emails somehow qualified as spam. They've updated to allow "do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email" through. Now I wonder what else I'm not getting. :( Thanks so much for your help and patience.

Comment: @TravisIllig thanks for the heads up! I was just digging in this morning and couldn’t find any indication of problems on our end... It’d be interesting to know why it was flagged as spam; maybe that’s something we can improve upon